# Как записать квинтиллион в mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Как записать квинтиллион (18 нулей) в mysql?
Я использую тип bigint, как мне сделать чтоб можно было записать квинтиллион?

Comment: Ознакомиться с типами полей мускула и узнать, что есть типы FLOAT, DOUBLE (REAL)

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую

Comment: А что не получается с BIGINT (Диапазон числа со знаком от –9223372036854775808 до 9223372036854775807. Диапазон числа без знака (unsigned) от 0 до 18446744073709551615.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать такие типы данных как VARCHAR или INT, то никак, там стоит ограничение по символам, данное число можно записать только если использовать тип данных TEXT, что конечно не является правильным, но иного способа я не знаю

Comment: интереса ради, а VARCHAR чем не подходит?